# variable change and reset logic

Tags: javascript

I'm noticing that I'm doing this a lot in my code.

I need to store the value of a variable so I can change it and restore it again. Let's say the variable is `var1`. I need to use the variable under the same name `var1` which means I need to make the value changes to it directly. But I don't want to lose the original value. So I store it somewhere `var1_original`, make the change to it, run the code I need to run, then restore the original value.

```
  var var1_original = var1;
  var1 = 'new value'; //I have to store the new value under the same name (var1) 

  //have some 
  //lines of code
  //here

  var1 = var1_original;
```

So, I need to do this on many variables (var1, color, dimArr, etc.) and of course the code that gets executed in the middle is different. Is there a way to create a function that would do saving and restoring, but still let the code in the middle run?

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the answer you want, but you could wrap the inner block in an anonymous function:

```
var1 = "original value";
(function(var1) {
    var1 += "... another value";
})(var1);
var1; // "original value"
```

That puts the inner block into a separate variable scope and allows you to reuse the `var1` variable name without changing it in the outer block. If you don't need to start with the original value in the inner block, you don't need to pass it in - you can just declare a new `var1` as a new variable with a `var` statement in the inner block.

Comment: It's not the answer I'm looking for, but +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i see what you mean. I think you don't need to store things. You can create a new variable and use that

```
var var1 = 'somevalue', var2 = 'anothervalue';
// do things using `var2`
// continue using 'var1'
```

Or, if the code must use `var1` as variable name, use a immediately invoked function to give it its own scope:

```
var var1 = 'somevalue';
//...
(function(){
  var var1 = 'othervalue';
  // do things to var
}());
//...
//continue with original var1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best you can get generally:

```
window.savedValues = {}
function cache(name, values) {
    if (typeof values == undefined) {
        return window.savedValues[name];
    } else {
        window.savedValues[name] = values;
    }
}

cache('foo', [var1, color, dimArr]);
// ...
var saved = cache('foo');
var1 = saved[0];
// ....
```

Some modern browsers support destructuring assingments, which makes the restoring part more convenient:

```
[var1, color, dimArr] = cache('foo');
```

Though I can't help but feel that something has gone horribly wrong if you need such a thing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be making a new variable instead of reusing the old one.  Otherwise it could get very confusing if the same name means to different things within the same straight-line block of code.

Comment: The code in the middle is using a variable by the name `var1` specifically. This is the reason for the change and reset, and it has to be done this way unfortunately.

Comment: Then move the code in the middle to a separate function?  Or better yet replace the use of var1 in that block.